# Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing

Tags: angular

I'm getting Cross-Origin Request Blocked:

> The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at
> http://localhost:8092/authenticate. (Reason: CORS header
> ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

This error occurs while executing an Angular 8 project when I click the login button.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Access-Control-Allow-Origin header work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header to the server endpoint (Note: this allows access from anywhere if used in production)